# Trigger to refresh DataView when user clicks a button inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel

We have the following code in an UpdatePanel.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="UpdatePanelSearch" 
    runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate> 
        <p>Parent Search:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" Width="207px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code in the VB file looks like this to handle clicking the Search button so a GridView will display data based on the value entered into the TextBox.

The GridView is also in a separate UpdatePanel:

```
Protected Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click

    GridViewParentsSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetData(strSearchText)
End Sub
```

We would like to create a trigger to update the GridView if that is the correct thing to do here.

Here is the GridView:

```
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:GridView
            ID="GridViewParentsSummary" 
            runat="server" 
            AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" 
            PageSize="3"
            >

            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherName" 
                    HeaderText="Father's Name" 
                    SortExpression="FatherName" />

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="MotherName" 
                    HeaderText="Mother's Name" 
                    SortExpression="MotherName" />

                <asp:ButtonField 
                    ButtonType="Button" 
                    CommandName="Select" 
                    Text="Select This Parent" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Can you show the needed code required to make the correct trigger that will refresh the GridView?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I moved the TextBox and Button into the same UpdatePanel as the GridView and it now works. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `GridView` is in another `UpdatePanel` it should also update when another `UpdatePanel` updates. By default, the `UpdatePanel.UpdateMode` property is set to `Always` and this will cause all `UpdatePanel` in page to refresh.

However, this is not always the desired behavior so many time you'll change it to `Conditional` which means that the `UpdatePanel` will be refreshed only if one of its triggers was fired. In that case, you need to add this line in the `ButtonSearch_Click` method:

```
gridUpdatePanel.Update() 'assuming gridUpdatePanel is the UpdatePanel with the grid
```

for more information about the `UpdateMode` property look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx